# Huge OBJ files in VS2008 C++ compilation compared with VS6

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, object, size

We have a large project, >1M lines of code in about 300 DLLs.
So far we've been using VS6.

I've now converted everything to VS2008, all compiles, links and more importantly - runs!

==>However... the resulting compiled OBJ files are X 10 bigger and linking is extremely slow, with the linker hitting >1GB of memory quite often.

Part of the implications are that I need to compile certain prjects with /bigobj.

Result is a build that went from about 1:45 on a desktop to 3h.
The DLLs and the LIBs are roughly the same size as in the old VS6 build.

I've read all I could find here but didn't find a remedy to this problem.
If it is additional DEBUG info - I don't want it. I had enough before. 
The size in release increased, but not so much...

Anyone has any idea? Or is my only option to break down the projects into much smaller units? Is refactoring my only hope?! Surely there's a secret flag I missed...

---

**Edit1 (13/07/2012 12:20BST)**
I've compared dumpbin of an Obj created by VS6 vs. VS2008. The one in 2008 *appears* as if "staticly linking". In VS6 it contains a few symbols all from the current DLL. In VS2008 it contains symbols from (probably) all libraries it is dependent upon. Dumpbin sizes are 66kb and 32,000kb for VS6 and VS2008, respectively.

---

Comment: Try disabling "debug information" in project settings (C++ branch).

Comment: _"We have a large project, >1M lines of code in about 300 DLLs. So far we've been using VS6."_  I'm never going to complain about my job again.

Comment: @IvanShcherbakov - won't this prevent me from easily debugging?

Comment: BTW satisfied Xoreax Incredibuild customer here. We've got a few big build servers here on site; over 90% of a build is offloaded to them.

Comment: @MSalters - we've tried incredibuild, and unfortunately we weren't satisfied. Initially it was my _preferred_ approach. Plus, as linking is the biggest bottleneck - Incredibuild doesn't solve this.

Comment: @aabramovich: When did you try? [IncrediLink](http://www.xoreax.com/webhelp/pages/advanced_incredilink.htm) is a fairly new feature. Also, if you turn off Local Task Execution, your PC will only do linking.

Comment: @MSalters - tried it fairly recently. I wasn't satisfied with their support, especially given the amount of money we were about to fork...

Comment: it's called Progress mate, get used to it :( I guess you could upgrade to VS2010, I'm sure they'll have made it more efficient by now :(:(

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Indeed, [they have](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/09/10/linker-throughput.aspx). The PDB writing is now done on a separate thread and doesn't delay the actual library building. Summary: 10-50% faster linking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your debugging options. `/Z7` causes large .OBJ files, `/Zi` puts the same information in a separate .PDB file.

Compiler option `/Oi` may help by inlining intrinsic function, which then no longer need to be linked. You probably don't want to debug `memset` anyway.

Turn off `/Gm` (incremental rebuild) so you can turn on `/MP` (parallel build). Also turn off `/Gy` - while it makes for smaller EXE's, it causes bigger OBJ files and slower linking.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters. We use /ZI. We use /MP, and GY is off. I also played with incremental vs. non-incremental linkage. Non-incremental is painful. Very. Adding /Oi now - will report in 12h

Comment: Incremental link runs out of memory and I can't find a way around it. Object size has reduced by about 25%, but they are still huge. I can't use the /3GB flag as many developers (erm) use laptops that have 3GB overall... I will try changing OS, as I have XP...

Comment: The `/3GB` flag refers to the address space for the executable built, and doesn't affect the compiler or linker itself. Furthermore, that's 3GB address space, which includes memory-mapped files, not RAM.

Comment: I've added some new info, if that makes any more sense of things... Thanks!

Comment: Makes sense, but can you also check what _type_ of symbols you have? It sounds like the majority are "UNDEF". Also, the summary should tell you what parts of you .OBJ contribute to its size. Are that the `.debug$S` and `.debug$T` sections?

Comment: String Table Size = 0xAFD9F8 bytes

  Summary

           4 .CRT$XCU
           8 .bss
        F905 .data
      D8B630 .debug$S
          8C .debug$T
      136BE8 .drectve
       24F43 .rdata
        D9C8 .rdata$r
           4 .rtc$IMZ
           4 .rtc$TMZ
        63FC .sxdata
      2D11AF .text
       555F2 .text$x
          AB .text$yc
          38 .text$yd
       58374 .xdata$x

Comment: That's a LOT of data/strings. All others are smaller than 0x100000, but data/strings are several times bigger.